# Delphi Rbuilder: Calculate value across multiple pages of data not just first and last page

Tags: delphi

I am using Rbuilder within a application constructed with Delphi.   I have a report already built that displays a list of items but then at the bottom I have some subtotal fields as well as a total field.  The subtotals and totals are defined as variables which then total up the cost of the individual items.

Unfortunately both the subtotals and totals only give me calculations for items on the first and last pages of data.  Lets say there are 5 pages of data that prints out.  Page one the totals are accurate.
Page two totals are accurate.   Page 3 totals include ONLY the totals from page 1 and page 3.  Page 4 total includes page 1 and page 4 and so on.      I have been trying to play around with timing settings as well as moving my code calculating the total to different operations (ongettext, onprint, oncalc, etc)

Has anybody ever run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I kept working at this and eventually found the problem.

At the report level I changed the report from TwoPass to OnePass.    That ended up giving me very close to what I wanted.  I ended up having to write some more code to get exactly what I wanted but changing the number of passes worked.

I was trying to display a running total page by page.  And as I changed pages it would update the value.
Onepass worked.